# How to have nvm run when nvmrc changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nvm

I am using [direnv](https://direnv.net/) and an `nvmrc` file to force `nvm install` to run every time you `cd` into the directory, making sure if you are running the project you are using the correct node version.

However, I noticed that if someone else changes the nvmrc file's version and I `git pull` (or rebase) the change, it doesn't automatically update my node version because it only runs when I enter the directory.

Has anyone done something to watch the nvmrc file or somehow make it change more often than just on `cd`?

Answer (score 0):

Since direnv's `.envrc` file is evaluated at each prompt, for your use case I would just place an explicit `nvm install <version number>` in your project's `.envrc`, e.g.:

```
nvm install 10.16.0
```

Although, personally, I prefer to just have an `nvm use <version number>` and let nvm itself point out that a given version of node isn't installed yet if the requested version isn't available.